# How to suppress query in the output of BTEQ REPORT Export

Tags: export, teradata

I am exporting data from a table and sending it as an e-mail through mainframe. It should get displayed in the contents of the mail. I get the rows of the table along with the query.

BTEQ:

```
.LOGON
.EXPORT REPORT DDNAME=OUTFILE;
.SET WIDTH=70;

SELECT NAME,AGE FROM TABLE;

.EXPORT RESET;
.LOGOFF;
```

Output:

```
17/05/31 SELECT NAME,AGE FROM TABLE.. Page 1
NAME   AGE
----   ---
xxx    20
bbb    24
```

Expected output:

```
NAME   AGE
----   ---
xxx    20
bbb    24
```

Please help me in removing the query from the output.

Comment: Mainframe? Try `.ECHOREQ OFF`

Comment: @dnoeth I tried your suggestion but it did not work out. I just got this from another link where you had suggested to use .EXPORT DATA FILE = ...; followed by  .SET RECORDMODE OFF; It worked for me. I hard coded the column names. Thanks for your help